# Not able to view pdf file in browser

Tags: html, pdf, web, browser

I need to display a `PDF` file in a `div`.
Here is what I have done so far.

```
<object data="D:\Report\428997.pdf" type='application/pdf' style='width: 100%; height: 700px'>
     <embed src='D:\Report\428997.pdf' type='application/pdf' style='width: 100%; height: 700px; border:0;' />
</object>
```

But, I am getting a blank gray color instead of the PDF.
I also tried changing the settings of Chrome to preview PDF.

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 0):

Lots of assumptions must be made, so I'm assuming either:

1. You're developing locally since you're using local file URLs `D:\Report…` . If so, I would strongly recommend setting up a [WAMP stack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/) so that you have a localhost setup and then make sure that the PDF you're testing is in the proper localhost (local server) path. Then you can definitively test whether it's a path issue. Alternatively, I can assume…
2. That you already have a WAMP-like/localhost setup in place, in which case the problem is that you're trying to access your local filesystem *(D:\…)* from it.

In either case, pointing to your local drive from within your html and not a server (or virtual server) path is likely contributing to your headaches.

*I'm assuming that you already know that your browser **can** open PDFs, and that your problem in particular is with this isolated code and not all PDFs.*